# Who is the author of this book - Sefer Maayan Moshe

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, moshe-rabbeinu

This book was mentioned in a Spanish YouTube channel. I was trying to reach out the author of the video, but I had zero response. I am wondering if someone knows about this book, if so, where can I get a print version?

[image: ספר מעין משה]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author of the sefer is Rabbi Moshe Shatz. The sefer is called [Maayan Moshe : Mavo L'Torat HaSod](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH990031506070205171/NLI)

There are several sites that you can use for buying it:

[MySefer](https://mysefer.com/Maayan-Moshe--Mavo-LTorat-HaSod__p-6092.aspx) (currently out of stock)

The blurb says:

> An introduction to understanding Kabbalah, based on the books Beyur Esser Sefirot (Rabbi Azriel of Gerona), and Derech Emunah (Rabbi Meir ben Gabbai).

[Otzar HaChochmah (online)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/168888/p/1/t/0281273981234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)

Comment: Shalom, @Shmuel thank you so much. May HaShem bless you!!!

Comment: @Carlos No problem at all and all the same! May G-d bless you and may He give you wisdom!

Answer (score 3):

R' Shatz has undertaken to no longer publish this sefer. In it's stead he released [Tarshish Shoham Veyashfeh](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/tarshish-shoham-veyashfeh-hatzimtzum-vehametzius-2-volume-set/38646) which is an updated and revised version.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!